# How to get the related view if can not use document by id in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wechat

I am program a litte-program, which is based on javaScript and imitative html, css's framework.

But, it did not own `document`, so can not use `id` to get a view.

Look at the picture I token form my progress:

[image]

The last 3 item is one kind view, and set the content `display:none`, I just want to consider the last 3 items' situation:

In my `search.wxml`:

```
<view wx:elif="{{show_view == 2}}" class="search-list" >
    <view class="big-list">
        <view class="list-name">【张ddd词典】</view>
        <view class="big-c">莲花生大忻州水电费那我羽绒服看了佛奥UR爱和如意烦死人就可以覅按时付款局if你真幸福也还UR和莲花生大忻州水电费那我羽绒服看了佛奥UR爱和如意烦死人就可以覅按时付款局if你真幸福也还UR和莲花生大忻州水电费那我羽绒服看了佛奥UR爱和如意烦死人就可以覅按时付款局if你真幸福也还UR和</view>
    </view>

    <view class="list">
        <view class="list-name" bindtap="foldDictionary">张ddd词典
            <view class="imgBox">
                <image src="../resource/search/up.png"></image>
            </view>
        </view>
        <view class="list-content">
            <view class="list-c">莲花生大忻州水电费那我羽绒服看了佛奥UR爱和如意烦死人就可以覅按时付款局if你真幸福也还UR和</view>
        </view>
    </view>

    <view class="list">
        <view class="list-name" bindtap="foldDictionary">张ddd词典
            <view class="imgBox">
                <image src="../resource/search/down.png"></image>
            </view>
        </view>
        <view class="list-content" style="display:none" >
            <view class="list-c">莲花生大忻州水电费那我羽绒服看了佛奥UR爱和如意烦死人就可以覅按时付款局if你真幸福也还UR和</view>
        </view>
    </view>

    <view class="list">
        <view class="list-name">张ddd词典
            <view class="imgBox">
                <image src="../resource/search/down.png"></image>
            </view>
        </view>
        <view class="list-content" style="display:none">
            <view class="list-c">莲花生大忻州水电费那我羽绒服看了佛奥UR爱和如意烦死人就可以覅按时付款局if你真幸福也还UR和</view>
        </view>
    </view>
</view>
```

In this code you can see the `style="display:none"` and `image src` is different in the last 3 view, in there I `bindtap` an event(named:`foldDictionary`) to the view's sub-view(which's class is "list-name").

Then in my `search.js`:

```
// fold or unfold dictionary
foldDictionary: function(e){
    // There I want to fold(if item is unfold) or unfold(if item is fold) the item view.
}
```

Because in this framework, there is no `document`, so can not use `id` to get the brother view or its superview.

So, how to do with that? unfold or fold my item?

Comment: I'd guess that `e.target` might be set to whichever element was tapped so maybe something like `e.target.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('list-content')[0]` would likely select the hidden `list-content` so setting `e.target.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('list-content')[0].style.display` should probably allow you to get what you want done hopefully the other is `this` may be set to the event target :) - although can only speculate as I'm not familiar with the framework you're using

Comment: @Brian, no, bro, can not use `getElementsByClassName`, because this is `document`'s related method, it is not available in the framework.

Comment: Ah k no worries - I would have expected that even if a root element didn't exist that an element would still be regular DOM elements which would mean those methods might exist. I can't see how this can be done unless they provide a method of doing so in their framework as without those or similar methods DOM traversal is impossible. My only other thought is perhaps you could overwrite the clicked views `innerHTML` in the event handler if that attribute is available. Although this could be a pain to implement without unintended side effects.